# "Une identité construite dans l'autrui" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions

Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte? Serait-il mieux de dire "construite par l'autrui" ?

Comment: Si cette phrase est tirée d'un papier, comme par exemple en philosophie ou psychologie, il y a une forte possibilité qu'il s'agisse d'un terme défini dans le domaine donné, soit plus ou moins standard soit défini dans le papier même. Il faut donc des détails sur le contexte, sinon on ne peut savoir si c'est correct ou non.

Comment: Tout dépend de ce que tu veux dire car ça ne dit pas la même chose. « construite par l'autrui » implique que c'est l'autrui qui construit l'identité, « construite dans l'autrui » implique que l'identité est construite par un sujet indéfini dans ta phrase (ou alors se construit elle-même) dans un environnement qui est « l'autrui ». Je pense que la question est trop vague pour obtenir une réponse plus précise.

Comment: Le problème, c'est qu'il manque une partie de la question. Serait-il mieux de dire.... ou de dire....? De plus, ce n'est pas une phrase, mais trois mots sans verbe et sans sujet. Il faut reformuler la question, car c'est impossible à comprendre. J'ai beau me gratter la tête...

Answer (score 3):

> Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte ?

Oui, la phrase est grammaticalement correcte.

> Serait-il mieux de dire "construite par l'autrui" ?

Ni mieux ou moins bien, la phrase aurait simplement une autre signification :

***Dans*** indique **où** / **comment** est construite l'identité (*autrui* a un rôle d'objet: l'identité est construite dans l'autrui) alors que ***par*** indique **qui** / **quoi**  la construit (*autrui* joue le rôle de sujet : l'autrui construit l'identité).

Tout dépend donc du sens attendu.

Comment: Tu n'envisages pas le cas où le PO voudrait justement dire que c'est l'autrui qui construit cette identité ?

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous Ah, je comprends ce que tu veux dire. Je n'envisageais pas ce cas. Je corrige.

Comment: C'est pour ça que je lui ai demandé des précisions... (unclear what you're asking).

Comment: +1 super merci... ! C'est marrant comme... les fonctions grammaticales se superposent aux entités métaphysiques... ;-)